# c # desktop app error 401 How can I send the data

Tags: c#, .net, api, http-post

I do not have a problem getting tokens in the desktop application I developed. But when I try to send data, I get a 401 error.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;
string requestParams = "";
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "112233");
webRequest.Headers.Add("AccessToken", token);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(req);
webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
     requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse()) 
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
             StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
             string Json = rdr.ReadToEnd();         
        }
}
```

Comment: You do know what a 401 code means, don't you? Not sure what kind of help you expect from us.

Comment: yes I know. just have errors as code?

Comment: 401 means issues with the authentication. You might be using a wrong token, wrong api key or you are not passing the token correctly. You need to figure out what the service needs. Are you sure it needs both an access token and an api key? Are you sure you need `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`?

Comment: There is no problem when I test it with postman.
yes it wants token and api key
I'm not sure about CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Comment: Try removing `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`. It might interfere with the authentication as it sets the credentials to the credentials the application is running with.

Comment: I tried but the error continues

Comment: And in postman you use the same headers (note: in code your are not using the authorization header)

Comment: i updated as below but it didn't work   
 webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post to api with c # windows form application. oauth2.0

```
            using (var client1 = new HttpClient ())
            {
                client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token());
                client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "xxxx");

                var builder = new UriBuilder(new Uri("you - url"));

                HttpRequestMessage request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, builder.Uri);

                request1.Content = new StringContent("{\"values\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject("you -data")+ "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
               
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client1.SendAsync(request1);

            };
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to answer for the question asked. An explanation is equally important with the code posted.

Comment: Post to api with c # windows form application. oauth2.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about setting the token. First, you need to be sure what your server wants as a token. You can try this for the `Bearer` token.

```
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your program to work, you have to provide an actual URL, not just the string `"url"`, in

> webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");

Comment: I have a actual URL.